# How to avoid nested data attributes when fetching that through graphql?

Tags: javascript, graphql, axios

Im use to the traditional REST API:

```
  axios({
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/GetUsers',

  }).then(function(response) {


    // Array of objects containing users
    console.log('done', response.data);

  });
```

In graphql:

```
  axios({
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
    data: {
      query: `{ users { Email }}`,
    },
  }).then(function(response) {
    // notice the doubble data call
    console.log('done', response.data.data.users);
  });
```

In graphql im forced to call `.data.data.users` to get my data and im wondering is there 
a way to get it through `response.data` as in a REST API call so that I dont need the call to `.data` and `.users`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not, it's standard behaviour - response format defined in specs.

- not needed as usually [react] components works on `data` prop or `useQuery` (apollo) returns `data`
- response can contain `error` property beside to `data` (sibling)

You can always assign shortcut

```
const data=response.data.data;
```

... and later use only `data.users` or

```
const users=response.data.data.users;
```

... if you really need this.